# form render custom symfony2

Tags: symfony

hi i am trying to make a form with validations.

I have this form:

```
<form  class="formulario" id="modificarmedico" action="{{ path('medico_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    <div id="mio_miobundle_medicotype">
    {{ form_row(edit_form.username) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.dni) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.nombre) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.apellido1) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.apellido2) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.localidad) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.provincia) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.direccion) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.telefono) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.movil) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.titulacion)}}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.numero)}}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.fechaalta)}}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.idioma)}}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.tema)}}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.color)}}
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_A') %}
        {% if entity.id == app.user.id %}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.password) }}
         {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
            <div class="empoculto"> 
                {{ form_row(edit_form.activo) }}
                {{ form_row(edit_form.generar) }}
            </div>
        {% else %}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.generar) }}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.activo) }}
        <div class="empoculto">
            {{ form_row(edit_form.password) }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
         {{ form_row(edit_form.password) }}
         {{ form_row(edit_form.password) }}
        <div class="empoculto">
        {{ form_row(edit_form.generar) }}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.activo) }}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

but the password errors shows me outside the div. not so with the other fields:

```
<div>
   <label for="mio_miobundle_medicotype_movil" class=" required">Móvil</label>
   <ul>
      <li>El campo debe tener 9 números.</li>
      <li>El campo debe tener sólo números.</li>
   </ul>
   <input type="text" id="mio_miobundle_medicotype_movil" name="mio_miobundle_medicotype[movil]" required="required" maxlength="9" value="fgadfg" />
</div>
<div><label for="mio_miobundle_medicotype_color" class=" required">Color*</label><input type="text" id="mio_miobundle_medicotype_color" name="mio_miobundle_medicotype[color]" required="required" value="#1153ed" /></div>
<ul>
   <li>Las contraseñas deben ser iguales.</li>
</ul>
<div><label for="mio_miobundle_medicotype_password_Nueva contraseña" class=" required">Nueva contraseña</label><input type="password" id="mio_miobundle_medicotype_password_Nueva contraseña" name="mio_miobundle_medicotype[password][Nueva contraseña]" required="required" /></div>
<div><label for="mio_miobundle_medicotype_password_Repite contraseña" class=" required">Repite contraseña</label><input type="password" id="mio_miobundle_medicotype_password_Repite contraseña" name="mio_miobundle_medicotype[password][Repite contraseña]" required="required" /></div>
```

i tried form_bubbling symfony2 but not solve my problem.
thanks.

Comment: why <ul>
   <li>Las contraseñas deben ser iguales.</li>
</ul> not inside div password?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement puts the errors in the div in one case and outside the div in the other (Actually it can't be determined since you did not post the entire form.)

```
    {% if entity.id == app.user.id %}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.password) }}
     {{ form_errors(form.password) }}          {# part of only one condition #}
        <div class="empoculto">                {# specifically handled here #}
            {{ form_row(edit_form.activo) }}
            {{ form_row(edit_form.generar) }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.generar) }}
    {{ form_row(edit_form.activo) }}
    <div class="empoculto">                   {# how to handle errors #}
        {{ form_row(edit_form.password) }}    {# not specified here #}
    </div>                                    {# probably handled by #}
    {% endif %}                               {# form default #}
```

Also

```
{{ form_errors(form.password) }}
```

should probably be

```
{{ form_errors(edit_form.password) }}
```